# solving Can't open perl script "all_gen_cmf_image": No such file or directory error

Tags: image, perl, image-processing, grip

i work on image copy move forgery detection field. i downloaded GRIP dataset form https://www.grip.unina.it/, there is some modification needed for the images and can be done with perl functions downloaded with the dataset. it is the first time for me to work with .pl functions. i downloaded the program form this website  https://platform.activestate.com/create-project?language=perl, and followed the setup steps.
now i have two problems: the first one, when i tried to run the function this error appeared "Can't open perl script "all_gen_cmf_image": No such file or directory", i have added the scripts directory using cd.

the second problem i don't know what he mean with this line "update the "vole" variable in the configuration file db_configs.pl, it should point to your vole binary of CMFD framework." in reedme file.
can any one helping me solving this problem?

Comment: *"... and can be done with perl functions downloaded with the dataset"* : Can you provide a link to the functions? Then we can try reproduce. Also, the site https://www.grip.unina.it/ seems to be down?

Comment: thanks @ Håkon , i already emailed the others of the paper and database and waiting their answer for the website problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perl doesn't automatically try the `.pl` extension when you pass it the name of a script on the command line.<sup>[1]</sup> So, it fails because there isn't a script named "all_gen_cmf_image"; it's actually named "all_gen_cmf_image.pl". To run all_gen_cmf_image.pl you have to include the `.pl` part of the extension. Assuming you are in the scripts folder, the following should work:

```
perl all_gen_cmf_image.pl
```

or in the parent directory:

```
perl scripts/all_gen_cmf_image.pl
```

1. However, when Perl runs a `use Module;` statement, perl automatically adds `.pm` on the end and replaces any `::` in the module name with a slash.

Comment: thanks @Nathan Mills for you attention, i tried 'perl all_gen_cmf_image.pl' and added the path using cd, but still having the same error. i think the problem on the program setup, i will try to setup another version.